# Collect data in cache and writing to database

Tags: java, caching

I need some help in Caching.

Here is my requirement :

I am having an application which has millions of hits per day. Currently i am logging the information like session and transaction logs in log tables using direct db inserts, which is slowing down the performance of the application.

I want something like : I use some caching mechanism which should collect data per hit. I will write it to a file and as soon as the file contains lets say 1000 records, these entries from cache should go to the database as a single batch.(write behind would be good).

Can some please help in solving this ?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609840/ehcache-not-resume-db-writing-after-server-restart)?  Protocol on Stackoverflow is not to re-ask questions but to edit them to make them better.

Comment: That question was related to Ehcache. But i thought may be my requirement cant be achieved with that framework, so i posted it as new questions to get more ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:  Using log4j with an AsynAppender and a JDBCAppender.

You can configure the buffer size of your AsynAppender in the log4j.xml.  Then when the buffer is full, it will use the JDBCAppender to flush everything in the Database.

ex:

```
    <appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
     ....
     your DB CONFIG


    <appender name="PerfAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="5000" />
    <appender-ref ref="DB" />
</appender>
```

This way, it do what you describe, and you don't even have to write a line of code ;-) well almost...

More details:

You can persist the data using th MDC of log4J.  MDC is basically a hashmap in which you can store the data you wanna log (key,value).  Then in your log4j.xml you can access the data in the MDC with the %X.

ex:

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
<param name="URL" value="yoururlconnection" />

<param name="Driver" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
<param name="User" value="myuser" />

<param name="Password" value="mypassord" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
     <param name="ConversionPattern"        
         value="INSERT INTO mytable (field1, field2, etc) VALUES
                    ('%X{value1}', '%X{value2}', etc)" />
        </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Will this approach help in surviving a JVM crash? How do i persist data which this approach ?

Comment: added details in my response.  I dont know about the JVM crash!!! but you persist the data collected with log4j using the asynAppender->JDBCAppender.  The AsyncAppender will not impact the performance since it's Async.

Comment: This approach wont help me in production environment where logging will be turned off. Is there any other caching mechanism to achieve this ?

Comment: Probably, but i never implemented one.  I have implemented the log4j approach and it works very well.  I don't understand why the logging is turned off in prod...  The usual practice is to raise the log level to something other then DEBUG to avoid logging to much stuff.  But disabling it completely is a bit drastic ;-) IMO

Answer (score 0):

There is sure to be a Java interface to memcached that will solve this issue. In your logging code, just add the item to log to memcached, and then every X records write them all in one go.

In fact, you could do the batch writing in a separate process, so the user whose hit contains the cache write does not experience the additional delay.